# django celery delay function dont exetute

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

hello I want to use celery tasks in my Django project and  I try to follow this very good [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=sharer) from Mr.Vitor Freitas.

but in my case and if try to run it that tutorial [project](https://github.com/sibtc/django-celery-example) i don't get results back the functions don't execute and in my case and in tutorial(i take message to wait and refresh and nothing after refresh).

Any idea Why ?

I think so the problem maybe is in RABBITQM server ?some configuration ?

Just install Erlang(`otp_win64_20.1.exe`) and after RabbitMQ(`rabbitmq-server-3.6.12.exe`)

here example code :

settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

app = Celery('mysite')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

tasks.py

```
import string

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def create_random_user_accounts(total):
    for i in range(total):
        username = 'user_{}'.format(get_random_string(10, string.ascii_letters))
        email = '{}@example.com'.format(username)
        password = get_random_string(50)
        User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
    return '{} random users created with success!'.format(total)
```

---

```
_ _init_ _.py

from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.shortcuts import redirect

from .forms import GenerateRandomUserForm
from .tasks import create_random_user_accounts


class UsersListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'core/users_list.html'
    model = User


class GenerateRandomUserView(FormView):
    template_name = 'core/generate_random_users.html'
    form_class = GenerateRandomUserForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        total = form.cleaned_data.get('total')
        create_random_user_accounts.delay(total)
        messages.success(self.request, 'We are generating your random users! Wait a moment and refresh this page.')
        return redirect('users_list')
```

here details after cd my project path > `celery -A mysite worker -l info` :

```
C:\Windows\System32>cd C:\Users\username\Desktop\django-celery-example-master

C:\Users\username\Desktop\django-celery-example-master>celery -A mysite worker -l info

 -------------- celery@pc name v4.1.0 (latentcall)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Windows-8-6.2.9200 2017-10-29 18:10:24
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         mysite:0x404e5c0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . mysite.core.tasks.create_random_user_accounts

[2017-10-29 18:10:24,596: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: TypeError('must be integer<K>, not _subprocess_handle',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 370, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\concurrency\base.py", line 131, in start
    self.on_start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\concurrency\prefork.py", line 112, in on_start
    **self.options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 1007, in __init__
    self._create_worker_process(i)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 1116, in _create_worker_process
    w.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\process.py", line 124, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\context.py", line 383, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 64, in __init__
    _winapi.CloseHandle(ht)
TypeError: must be integer<K>, not _subprocess_handle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\spawn.py", line 159, in spawn_main
    new_handle = steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\reduction.py", line 126, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
WindowsError: [Error 6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Celery 4.x does not support Windows](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-celery-support-windows), and in my experience it's the prefork/billiards parts that break. Running the worker with [`--pool solo`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-p) should work.

Comment: how to do that ?I need other celery version ?

Comment: You can use `pip install celery==3.1.25`.